# How to discover the value of the attribute display of an html tag?

Tags: html, tags, display

I don't want to have to do tests to check if the tag accepts receiving width or height, to differentiate inline from inline-block, nor test to see if it starts on a new line or not, to differentiate from block.

I would like a kind of var_dump() for the tag, like the one provided by Developer Tools (unfortunately it doesn't provide the same for tags like img and span):

```
textarea {
writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
font-style: ;
font-variant-ligatures: ;
font-variant-caps: ;
font-variant-numeric: ;
font-variant-east-asian: ;
font-variant-alternates: ;
font-weight: ;
font-stretch: ;
font-size: ;
font-family: monospace;
font-optical-sizing: ;
font-kerning: ;
font-feature-settings: ;
font-variation-settings: ;
text-rendering: auto;
color: fieldtext;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
appearance: auto;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
resize: auto;
cursor: text;
white-space-collapse: preserve;
text-wrap: wrap;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
background-color: field;
column-count: initial !important;
margin: 0em;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
border-image: initial;
padding: 2px;
```

}

Comment: why not simply use the console and check the default?

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have an image element like this:

```html
<img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Image">
```

To check the default display value, add an id to the image element like this:

```html
<img id="myImage" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Image">
```

Now get the computed style (which should be the default if not changed by any of your own css) by executing the following in your developer console:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("myImage");
window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("display")
```

This will return the default styling for the specified element.